# TSQL Bring back group when it contains a certain value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following information in a SQL Server table. I am looking to see if there is a way to search by Area e.g. Ireland and bring back rows 1, 2, 5 and 6 which shows the managers in Ireland details and also any other countries information where they also look after.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `EXISTS` would be one method:

```sql
SELECT Num,
       Area,
       ManagerName,
       NumerCustomers
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dbo.YourTable E
              WHERE E.ManagerName = YT.ManagerName
                AND E.Area = 'Ireland');
```

Comment: If it answers the question, @Braggart , please do accept it as the solution; then future users know the answer was helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**You could also use a windowed conditional count:**

```sql
SELECT
  Num,
  Area,
  ManagerName,
  NumerCustomers
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        CountIreland = COUNT(CASE WHEN t.Area = 'Ireland' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY t.ManagerName)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE t.CountIreland > 0;
```